# How do I select an element with [] in its name attribute?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to create a new style for phpmyadmin with the browser extension [stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne).

How can I select this select by name:

```
<select name="criteriaTables[]" multiple="">
```

I tried it like this:

```
form#db_search_form select[name=criteriaTables] {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

...but it does not work.

```
form#db_search_form select[name=criteriaTables[]] {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

...does not work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the attribute value in quote marks (`"`):

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}

select[name="criteriaTables[]"] {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<select name="criteriaTables[]" multiple="">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively, you can also escape the square brackets:

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}

select[name=criteriaTables\[\]] {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<select name="criteriaTables[]" multiple="">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below.

```
<style type="text/css">

select[name^="criteriaTables"] {
    min-height: 400px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will also select `<select name="mYcriteriaTables" multiple="">`

Comment: @BenM To be fair, it *is* correct, because it will work, but it's not a *good* solution because it will work *too well* by selecting other elements (depending on OP's markup).